# Cosmos db - how to combine different results values in one result's particular attributes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I don't how can I explain this question, but suppose I have cosmos db container which look like this

**Query** -

```sql
select c.Name,c.Value from c where c.Name = "abc"
```

**Result** -

```json
[
  {
    "Name":"abc",
    "Value":{"a":5,"b":6}
  },
  {
    "Name":"abc",
    "Value":{"a":1,"b":2}
  }
]
```

Now I wanted to combine these value as array in singal results like this

```json
 {
    "Name":"abc",
    "Values":[
         {"a":5,"b":6},. 
         {"a":1,"b":2}
    ]
 }
```

What SQL query should I run

Comment: Don't think that's possible. Cosmos can't relate different documents to eachother. The closest thing that is possible is the `GROUP BY` operator, but that only allows aggregate functions. It also conflicts with the way results are retrieved iteratively.

Comment: That's what I told to my manager but she is not understanding ☹️

Comment: You could achieve this result using a cosmos stored procedure that gets the data as in your question and then uses custom code to group it and return it. Or do the same but in the application that retrieves the data (preferable).